# How to print to pdf the ER Diagram in the SQL Database in 1 Page?

Tags: sql, sql-server, erd

At present, ER Diagram is fallen to multiple pages. It doesn't show the table relations correctly.

How to print to pdf the ER Diagram in the SQL Database in 1 Page?

Comment: Just use the printing preferences in the setup dialog. Then choose to fit on one page.

Comment: Nope.. I found the answer. Go to Database Diagram on the Top - selections. Under Database Diagram -> Zoom -> Change the preference accordingly

Comment: That works too. Or you could get a large format printer. ;)